# What is the formal definition of the symbol $\int f(x)\,dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Today, I was explaining integration by parts to a fellow student, a freshman.

I ended up demonstrating how to calculate $\int e^{2x}\sin(3x)\,dx$ by iterative integration. At the end, I ended up with the equality

$$\frac{13}{4}\int e^{2x}\cos(3x)\,dx = \frac{1}{2}e^{2x}\sin(3x)-\frac{3}{4}e^{2x}\cos(3x)$$

and so

$$\int e^{2x}\cos(3x)\,dx = \frac{4}{13}\left(\frac{1}{2}e^{2x}\sin(3x)-\frac{3}{4}e^{2x}\cos(3x)\right).$$

This made me question what $\int f(x)\,dx$ even means to begin with. My textbook states that $\int f(x)\,dx$ denotes *any* of the primitive functions to $f(x)$. But if so, I've just showed that *all* of the primitive functions to $f(x)$ are equal to the right hand side of the second equation. This can obviously not be the case, as I could just add on any non-zero constant to obtain a new primitive.

So I guess my question is: what is the formal definition of the symbol $\int f(x)\,dx$?

EDIT: Turns out I was simply forgetting to add constants, as per Thomas' comment below. $\int f(x)\,dx$ does indeed denote an arbitrary primitive to $f$ when $f$ is defined on some interval.

Comment: This is a great question, although it has been asked before here. The short answer is: "$\int f(x)dx$" is really referring to a *set of* functions, and when we write e.g. "$\int f(x)dx=g$" we mean that $g$ is *an element of* that set. Compare this with the similar abuse of "$=$" involved in [big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: It is not true that $\int u(x)v’(x)\,dx +\int v(x)u’(x)\,dx =u(x)v(x).$ $uv$ is one possibly value for this sum, but you need to add a constant to the right side to get all possible values. When you repeat the integration by parts, you have to apply a different constant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber That seems fair. Though I'll have to revisit the proof of ingration by parts in order to fully grasp why everything has just magically worked out for me this past year every time I've integrated by parts, in spite of my abuse of notation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews It's more complicated than just "add a constant" though, unless we're restricting attention to **connected** domains.

Comment: @SimonSMN It's the same issue. An expression like "$\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx$" needs to be understood as referring to a *set of* functions, namely the set of sums of elements of $\int f(x)dx$ and elements of $\int g(x)dx$. So when we write "$\int f(x)dx+\int g(x)dx=h(x)$," that's really shorthand for "there is an $F$ in the set $\int f(x)dx$ and a $G$ in the set $\int g(x)dx$ such that $F+G=h$."

Comment: @NoahSchweber Thank you very much. I'll leave this question up as I think your comments (in particular your comment about what we mean when we write $"\int f(x)\,dx + \int g(x)\,dx = h(x)$) provide further clarity. I bet someone else will find them useful some day.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok. Do you agree with Noah's definition of $\int f(x)\,dx$? If not, surely $\int f(x)\,dx$ must refer to a *specific* function? How would we choose which function it refers to?

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I am intrigued and confused by your comment about connected domains. How does indefinite integral notation apply to domains that aren't connected?

Comment: @RobArthan Consider, for example, the set of antiderivatives of the function $f(x)={1\over x}$ defined on $(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)$. The point is that since that domain has two connected components, we can have antiderivatives whose difference is **not** just a constant; rather, we need "one constant on the left and another on the right." As far as notation goes, "$\int f(x)dx$" still makes sense as the set of antiderivatives of $f$ even if the domain of $f$ isn't an interval.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Seems like $\int f(x)\,dx$ *can* be taken to denote the set of primitive functions of $f$, but given that I'm basically always working with intervals, I'm more inclined to go with Thomas' definition. Turns out I was just neglecting the implicit arbitrary constant in integration by parts.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I see. I never think of $\int f d x$ as a notation for an antiderivative but as a notation for an indefinite integral, i.e., the function that maps a pair $(a, b)$ to $\int_a^bf(x)dx$, when the latter exists. If you use it as a notation for antiderivatives, then I agree that things are more complicated.

Comment: @SimonSMN That's certainly fair - but you do have to keep in mind, then, the domain restriction.

Comment: @RobArthan Ah yes that's fair. (And to the OP, even though you're more interested in functions with connected domain it's a good exercise to tease out how Rob Arthan's interpretation differs from mine in terms of the sets they describe. The function ${1\over x}$ is a bad example here since it can't be integrated around $0$, but if you pick a better example ...)